# Streamlit displays blank image after applying OpenCV function

Tags: python, opencv, streamlit

I have this website written in Streamlit, my goal is to detect color of an image choosen by user and the user have to insert the HSV range range value manually on the `number_input` form, I have inserted HSV range for yellow color in order to test it

```
def detect_color(img,low_val_list: list[int], upper_val_list: list[int]):  
        lower_val = np.array(low_val_list)
        upper_val = np.array(upper_val_list)

        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,lower_val,upper_val)
        st.image(mask)
        return mask

def detection():
    get_img = st.file_uploader('Upload An Image',type=['png','jpg','jpeg','webm'])
    select_det = st.sidebar.selectbox('Select Detection Category',
                                      ['Color Detection',
                                      'Eye Pupil Detection',
                                      'Edge Detection',
                                      'Car Detection'])
    if select_det == "Color Detection":
        if get_img is not None:
            st.image(get_img)

            original_image = Image.open(get_img)
            original_image = np.array(original_image)

            option_form = st.sidebar.form('option_form')
            lower0 = int(option_form.number_input('Lower Range Value 1',min_value=0,max_value=255,value=1,step=1))
            lower1 = int(option_form.number_input('Lower Range Value 2',min_value=0,max_value=255,value=1,step=1))
            lower2 = int(option_form.number_input('Lower Range Value 3',min_value=0,max_value=255,value=1,step=1))

            detect = option_form.form_submit_button('Apply')

            option_form1 = st.sidebar.form('options_form1')
            upper0 = int(option_form1.number_input('Upper Range Value 1',min_value=0,max_value=255,value=1,step=1))
            upper1 = int(option_form1.number_input('Upper Range Value 2',min_value=0,max_value=255,value=1,step=1))
            upper2 = int(option_form1.number_input('Upper Range Value 3',min_value=0,max_value=255,value=1,step=1))

            detect1 = option_form1.form_submit_button('Apply')
            
            low_val = [lower0,lower1,lower2]
            upper_val = [upper0,upper1,upper2]
            if detect or detect1:
                st.subheader(low_val)
                st.subheader(upper_val)
            apply = st.button('Apply detector')
            if apply:
                detect_color(original_image,low_val,upper_val)
```

Turned out the website throws blank image after the button that supposed to display and apply the color detector function has been pressed. Main problem is that it throws blank image while I was expecting for it to display the original image that have been applied the HSV range values inserted by the user.

The picture:

[image]

Comment: Did you test the entered HSV range separately on your image?

Comment: @Jeru Luke If you meant by filling each value on each form then yes

Comment: what exact values? please work on a [mre]. this problem does not require any of the other stuff that looks like "streamlit". a MRE of this situation probably takes 5 lines of code, not 50.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz 
I put on HSV values **[25,150,50]** for lower range and **[35,255,255]** for upper range  (from the user number input form). I'm not sure what you meant by 'This situation probably takes 5 lines of code', because I'm providing a code that should takes user input from  the streamlit form (6 forms) then apply the OpenCV detection model on that user input HSV range value, there's no logic in it that it should be less than 50 lines of code.

Comment: I mean, you should review [mre]. seriously. I'm not linking to that because it's fun but because the code you present contains a lot of stuff you should have already debugged and determined that it's not contributing to the error. clearly the bug is _either_ how you _get_ the value using streamlit, _or_ how you _use_ the value with OpenCV. either, or. so investigate which it is, and discard the other part. we don't need to see both parts.

Comment: and what even is that picture? we can't *reproduce* anything without that picture. the goal of a MRE is that _we_ have a chance to do the debugging that you don't do. even if the code isn't minimal, at least with the input data it would be halfway reproducible. without data, it's not. do you realize why this is asked of you? you get free help here. make it at least _possible_ to help you. it's impossible without these things.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz There is it, I added the picture

Comment: for that `cvtColor` and `inRange` call, given that picture and the ranges you say in the comments, I get this mask: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSSxl.png (a hue of 30/180 (uint8) represents a hue of 60 degrees, which is yellow) -- you say `st.image(mask)` but then return just the mask, which is a numpy array. what was that `st.image` call for?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I used `st.image` in order to display the original image that has been applied the mask on my webapp.